# Does The Ethereum Wallet / Mist Standard Multisig Wallet Support ERC20 Tokens?

Tags: tokens, multisignature, erc-20

This question was prompted by [Any multisig wallets for Ether?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5qizrw/any_multisig_wallets_for_ether/):

> Are there any multisig wallets available for ether and other ethereum-based tokens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update Feb 21 2018

Note that while the sending of ETH and tokens works, you cannot change the parameters of the multisig (add owner, remove owner, change owner, change daily limit). See https://github.com/bokkypoobah/EthereumWalletMultisigTest for further information.

---

The standard Ethereum Wallet / Mist multisig contract does support ERC20 tokens.

Here is a transaction of a Golem Network Token (GNT) transfer from a multisig contract - [tx 0x4afd4e13bc80c7a9305b77f0f62058c8700ec6c92ad0c355f667af898903866b](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4afd4e13bc80c7a9305b77f0f62058c8700ec6c92ad0c355f667af898903866b) .

The multisig contract is at [0xf3f1f928fbe5d68b776005cad5350b49b42dfdde](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf3f1f928fbe5d68b776005cad5350b49b42dfdde).

From the transaction data, you can see the `execute(...)` multisig function call:

```
Function: execute(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data)

MethodID: 0xb61d27f6
[0]:000000000000000000000000a74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d
[1]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[2]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
[3]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044
[4]:a9059cbb000000000000000000000000550bfe4a2691175e03e058d826829c3a
[5]:749b5f9700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053444835
[6]:ec58000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`a74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d` is the GNT contract address.

And here is the portion of the GNT transfer function call.

```
a9059cbb  // web3.sha3('transfer(address,uint256)').substring(0,10) = "0xa9059cbb"
000000000000000000000000550bfe4a2691175e03e058d826829c3a749b5f97 // destination address 
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053444835ec580000 // new BigNumber("53444835ec580000", 16)/1e18 = 6
```

The user trying to execute the transaction above had a few failed attempts using their multisig account to execute this ERC20 transfer transaction due to insufficient gas. The user increased the supplied gas and the transaction executed smoothly.

Some further details on multisig wallets executing contract functions at [How Does The Ethereum Multisig Contract Wallet Execute Contract Functions?](https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/how-does-the-ethereum-multisig-contract-wallet-execute-contract-functions/).

Comment: Hey, how can you send this kind of transaction through MyEtherWallet? Do I have to write the Input Data by hand?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately.