# How to transfer ERC20 tokens from a multisig wallet?

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet, erc-20, multisignature

How can I transfer ERC20 tokens from a multisig wallet?

According to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11724/does-the-ethereum-wallet-mist-standard-multisig-wallet-support-erc20-tokens), it is possible to send a token from a multisig by setting the `to` parameter as the token contract's address and setting the `data` parameter to make it execute a `transfer` function to the final address.

However, writing the `data` field by hand seems too cumbersome and error prone. Is there an easier way to accomplish this? For example, with MyEtherWallet or other online services.